# Using 'realloc()' during runtime gives crash, why? - C Language

Tags: c

I have an array that I want to increase the size of during runtime. I assign values to the elements of the array by using a loop, and when the index of the loop hits the number of elements of the array, I want to increase the size of the array.

What I did, actually works; I can assign values to elements of the array that I would normally not be able to assign any values to without increasing the array's size. The bad side is, it gives me a crash after the program runs and finishes smoothly. What is wrong here? Is it that maybe the memory that I try to allocate for the array is already filled?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[3];
    int num_of_elements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); // This gives '3', I checked

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {  
        if(i == num_of_elements)
        {
            num_of_elements = num_of_elements + 10;
            realloc(arr, num_of_elements);
        }
        arr[i] = i+10;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are invoking undefined behavior. From [**standard §7.22.3.5**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5)

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the `malloc`
>   function for the specified size. **Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a
>   pointer earlier returned by a memory management function**, or if the
>   space has been deallocated by a call to the free or `realloc` function,
>   **the behavior is undefined.** If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is
>   unchanged.

By memory management function - it means `malloc` etc. `arr` is not dynamically allocated memory. So passing this to `realloc` is undefined behavior - in your case that behavior leads you to crash in program.

It would work if you do this

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
if( arr == NULL){
  perror("Malloc failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

...
int *p = realloc(arr,num_of_elements*sizeof(int));
                       ^^^^^
if(p == NULL ){
   perror("realloc failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
arr = p;
```

Check how `realloc` is used.

The takeaways will be:-

- Check the return value of `realloc`, `malloc`.
- You were trying to reallocate extra 10 elements for which you need `10*sizeof(int)` amount of memory.
- **Don't do** `arr = realloc(arr,SIZE)` in case `realloc` fails you will have memory leak.

#### Why `realloc` to `p` after all you do `arr=p` annyway?

Two reasons so far

- The answer to this is when `realloc` fails then it returns `NULL` now if you assign `arr` to `NULL` then you may have a situation where you lose the only reference to the previously allocated memory - leading to a memory leak. That's why we do it like this.
- Note this from standard

> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (**which *may*
>   have the same value as a pointer to the old object**), or **a null pointer
>   if the new object could not be allocated**.

Notice that `may` part - it might be the same address as before as pointed by `arr` or it might be different one. That explains why we should store it in some temporary pointer and then we assign it later.

Comment: Would it have hurt them to allow using realloc with a statically allocated memory :/ So you are saying that I need to dynamically allocate memory for 'arr', am I right? If so, how do I do that as simple to understand as possible? Oh alright you're editing your answer

Comment: @EmirhanG..:Yes. It is wrong what you did. You can't do that. And secondl, yes you are right. I have shown the correct way. Read the `man` pages - check the documentation linked.

Comment: Also, it's always good to duplicate the array size of each realloc. It's a good practice that I learned in college for dynamic allocation and works fine to me. But it's just a suggestion

Comment: @MaximillianForasteiro.:Please clarify what you are saying.

Comment: Hmm, interesting that you had to do 'arr = p' at the end, while they are the same address anyway. I understand the way you implemented things, thanks a lot /\

Comment: @EmirhanG.: There is reason for that line and I explained it, will clarify more.

Comment: @coderredoc it's more about the code posted by emirhan, he/she increase in 10 units the size of the array, if you duplicate, you'll do less realloc operations than if you increase the size by ten for big entries numbers

Comment: @EmirhanG. Prior to the assignment, `p` and `arr` are *not* certain to have the same value.  In fact, they are relatively unlikely to have the same value, even when `realloc()` succeeds.  It is possible that `realloc()` can change the size in-place, but even then it is not guaranteed that `realloc()` will do so.

Comment: @MaximillianForasteiro.: Yes I get your point - you are saying we should always double the number of elements we `realloc` that way we have to reallocate less number of times. But yes in this context I can punch in so many things in my answer. But yes there will obviously be a number of time we reallocate vs memory lying unused debate. :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger.: Yes just pushing the standard. So yes that is a reason too.

Comment: @MaximillianForasteiro.:well yes you can always allocate more and then later after use,you reduce its size to free unused space. Just one realloc call will do that thing. This has added benefit of both..less realloc calls and lesser unused space.(for small number of unused space you can leave it also).

Comment: @MaximillianForasteiro Good idea (multiplication instead of addition) 
@JohnBollinger , @coderredoc Alright, got it, the newly allocated address might not be the same as the original. But I have a question. Suppose that after saying the line `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);` , I went ahead and assigned values to 'arr', like arr[0] = some number etc... When I make a new pointer (int *p) and give it the value of the returned adress of 'realloc(arr, new_size)', what happens is that the 'realloc' function allocates new memory of size 'new_size' and then moves over the contents of arr to there

Comment: @EmirhanG..: Sorry for the late reply..contents are copied. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You should have done this:

```
arr = realloc(arr, num_of_elements);
^^^^^
```

`realloc()` does not necessarily extend or shrink the allocated memory **in-place**, it invalidates the dynamic memory that its first argument points to and allocates new memory, while preserving the content of the previous memory.

One possible implementation is :

```
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
    void* ret = malloc(size);
    if (ret == NULL) return ret;
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        memcpy(ret, ptr, /* previous size from system */);
        free(ptr);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: He should *not* have done as you suggest, for reasons detailed in the other answer.  But you are quite right that `realloc()` does not necessarily reallocate in place.  Erroneously assuming that it does is one of the main sources of bugs revolving around use of this function.